# PHP 5.6 Singleton?

Tags: php, singleton

I just copied singleton template from [phptherightway](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)

I use PHP 5.6.3 (cli) And I got this error:

[image: singleton error]

Can somebody explain this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the late static binding against a private property that's causing the problems.

Either modify the visibility of `$instance` to protected

Or modify the references to `static::$instance` in `getInstance()` to `self::$instance`